# Characterization of $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ by Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

We denote by $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ the dual space to $H_0^1(\mathbb{R^N})$. Let
$$\langle f,v \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} fv \hspace{1cm} (f,v \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)).$$
It is known that if $f \in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then there exists $f_0,f_1,\dots,f_N$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that
$$\langle f , v\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f_0v + \sum_{i=1}^N f_i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \hspace{1cm} (v \in H_0^1(\mathbb{R})).$$
Starting from this specific definition of $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, I want to prove that
$$H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \{ f \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^N) : (1+\vert y \vert^2)^{-1/2} \widehat{u} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N) \},$$
where $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^N)$ denotes the space of temperate distributions (dual space of the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions).

Is there any book/paper where I can find this result? Most of the time, the above characterization by Fourier transform is taken as a definition...

Thanks!

Comment: How has $H^1_0$ been defined?

Comment: As the closure of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^N) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. In fact, $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) = H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Comment: Do you have the characterization of   Fourier transforms of $H^1$ functions? They form a weighted $L^2$ space, with weight $w(x)=(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$. Then the dual of that space is another weighted $L^2$ space, with weight $w^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, I think this would be the easiest way to proceed; demonstrate that the corresponding property characterizes $H^1$.

Comment: I get the idea. However, I'm not familiar with weighted $L^p$-spaces and their duals. Let $X = L^2(\mathbb{R}^N,w(x)dx)$. Why is $X'$ of weight $w^{-1}$? How to define the pairing $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ between $X$ and $X'$?